# show structure of handles while programming in matlab

Tags: matlab, user-interface, structure, handles

Is it possible to see the structure of my struct variables while I'm programming?

I'm programming in matlab gui. I store my variables in the struct variable "handles". When I want to know how i structured the variable I have to run my programm and stop it while running to look up the structure of my variables.

Is it possible, that if I type in my code "handles" that I see a list of all containing variables (and other struct variables)?

(I know that from Visual Studio)

Comment: Although not perfect, I think the `Workspace browser`, combined with the `Variable Editor` are the closest match to what you are asking. Also if the variable already exist in the workspace, the _autocompletion_ feature should propose the different fields available.

Answer (score 1):

Matlab `Structure` type is a *dynamic type* - fields/members of the variables of this type can change during *run-time*. There is no trivial way to know before the execution of a program all the fields/members that certain `Structure` instance (variable) will contain.

I assum you worked with some statically-typed language in Visual Studio (`C#`, `C++` etc.). Members of variables in those languages are known at *compile-time* - that's the reason you can have useful tools providing you with that kind of interesting information.

If you want to know all the members of your variables before running the program in Matlab, there are two ways to do this:

- write down on a sheet of paper the members of your structure before writing a program; I advise that in this case you make the initialization of *all* of the structure variable members in some initial part of the code
- Matlab supports real classes through [Object-oriented programming](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/object-oriented-programming.html) (personally I didn't use this approach, because I found it to be too verbose)